# Can DDD/CQRS Aggregate Roots be microservices?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm currently designing the new system I strongly believe CQRS+ES would be a perfect fit for. I want to verify whether my "large scale" design presuppositions are sounding good and that I'm not moving in a wrong direction.

To me, it seems like a good idea to make each Aggregate Root (write model) live in its own microservice, due to coinciding consistency and network boundaries.

I think it's safe to assume that each aggregate instance may have just its own event stream, due to consistency guarantees. In practice, winding up an event store for each aggregate *instance* would be an overkill, but sharing one or few replicated event stores between the microservices of same aggregate type seems sane choice to me. If replication is not desired, we can even shard event stores based on the aggregate ID.

This way, with few aggregate-type-scoped microservices, each handling commands for lots of aggregate instances, scaling should be transparent enough to the rest of the system.

Then it makes sense for me to let Projectors (read models) live in their own microservices as well, each with their own DB, which should be shared between projectors of the same type.

Because projectors' query interface isn't very outer-world friendly (I assume that projectors provide Repository-like interface for issuing queries, which in my opinion doesn't play well with access control, rate limiting etc.), each projector should provide some unified network interface that would be used by BFF (backend-for-frontend), actually serving some API endpoints, ensuring security, providing versioning and so on.

[image: Badly drawn diagram of CQRS+microservices architecture]

**tl;dr:** I'm providing a graphical representation of above (encircled) to compensate my bad wording with my bad drawing. PS: Replay service is the service that monitors new events as they are appended into event store, and broadcasts them to the interested subscribed projectors or process managers (not drawn), OR replays entire event sequence for projectors with stale or empty DBs.

Does this CQRS+microservices adaptation sound good, or have I fundamentally misunderstood something and the whole design is trash?

**UPD1:**

#### Why do I have load balancer between event source and projectors and how do I balance the load?

If I'm spawning multiple projector instances of the same type to handle additional load from heavy queries, how they are going to listen for events? To me it seems strange to allocate just one instance to do all the event processing job, updating DB and so on, because with the load increase it's likely to get overloaded. So, it makes sense to distribute event handling as well, right?

Also, while I've been writing this, I've though whether it would be a good idea to further split projectors into "projector writers" (those listening for events and updating shared state in DB), and "projector readers" (those listening for queries and returning state), with the DB serving as a source of truth and consolidation point. This way we can better scale for asymmetric loads (little events, lots of queries) for no cost.

One of the necessary conditions is to prevent different projector writer instances from simultaneously handling events from the same aggregate, because updating the representation with out-of-order events will lead to the loss of internal consistency and immediate disaster.

As for "how", I can think of few solutions:

1. Keep single RabbitMQ queue for all incoming events, and make all projectors consume events from the queue with acknowledgements. Once DB has been updated, projector writer issues an ack to RabbitMQ and event is discarded from the queue. Otherwise, if projector writer dies for some reason, event will be requeued again to the next projector in line.

   For each aggregate we should keep the height/revision number, and only allow UPDATE to succeed if the next revision number (contained in the event) is exactly one more than current revision number. If this condition isn't true, then requeue this event in hope inconsistency would be resolved by then, and grab the next one.

   Eventually, it will complete, and given large enough number of aggregates it won't ever need to requeue.
2. Put some sort of dispatcher service to listen for events, one dispatcher per projector type. This dispatcher should distribute events to projector writers based on the hash of aggregate ID, so, the same aggregate is always handled by the same aggregate with index `hash(event.aggregateId) % numberOfProjectorWriters`.

   This will never requeue, but terminates MQ early, introduces single point of failure, and will screw up if number of projector writers changes due to some nodes dying, or scaling dynamically, or...
3. Somehow use header exchanges to implement the combo of #1 and #2, to make consumers prefer the same set of aggregate IDs, but without screwing up if number of consumers changes in the middle.

Comment: Why/how do you load-balance the Projectors (on the right side, the "building" side)?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu I've updated the question with answers. Feedback welcome. Also, those are not windows in the "building", those are cylinders, e.g. DB pictogram...

Comment: You are trying to preserve the order of events to respect to the Aggregates *only*; in general, readmodels (projections) need the events in a **total** order; otherwise, although it is possible, it would lead to a very complicated readmodel updater

Comment: But isn't total event order generally impossible? To my understanding, as there is no "global state", and there is no single point of consistency, how could be there any total ordering of events that happen simultaneously and independently? Of course, some kind of order can be provided by simply following timestamps, with the hope of eventual consistency, but it's not total, and to me it doesn't differ much from just randomly interleaving events from different aggregates. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's not impossible. There are EventStore implementations that make this possible. For example, in MongoDB, there is Timestamp that is kept synchronized using causal clocks between clients and server and even between shards

Comment: Other EventStores keep a global `sequence` number

Comment: To me these global sequence numbers and matrix clocks look like an attempt to force immediate consistency instead of eventual consistency, making global event store the single source of truth. Isn't this defeating the whole purpose of CQRS+ES?

Comment: Also, to my understanding, projectors don't really query events from the event store, they don't even have access to those, as event stores are owned by aggregates and hidden behind the event bus. So, projectors have to assume that events come in no defined order, and events from different aggregates may be arbitrarily skewed against each other. Am I wrong? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168191/discussion-between-toriningen-and-constantin-galbenu).

Comment: @toriningen what would this give in terms of number of microservices? Did you have a look at the concept of Bounded Context?

Comment: How exactly does the Replay service work?

Comment: @guillaume31 yes, I know about Bounded Contexts (how else can one apply DDD without knowing it?), but I don't see how they apply for microservices. Each bounded context is way too heavy to be scaled on its own, our huge app has just three BCs with more or less proportional load, but within BC load is very unbalanced, as different process managers are invoked with different rate.

Comment: Bounded Contexts don't have to be a one-to-one match with microservices, but thinking of microservices in terms of their own tailor-made model and language is a good approach, and [Context mapping strategies work well for them](https://youtu.be/sFCgXH7DwxM?t=1368). If you decide to apply a systematic 1-microservice-per-aggregate rule, you might end up with a hard to maintain entanglement of microservices, though YMMV depending on the domain model.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that though technically aggregate roots can live in their own microservices, such level of granularity may bring non-needed complexity. Usually they say, start with well-architected monolith.

Usually, if there are a few aggregates in a BC, they may share some services, repositories, so such aggregates together brings sensible reduction in complexity, as well as makes a cohesive component. But it may depend on scaling needs.

By the way, what event store consistency guarantees do you mean? The most useful guarantee for event stream is the ordering of events. Which is really hard to achieve in distributed environment. It would be great, if you provide a link to such guarantees for candidate event stores.

I agree with you, that read models may be located in separate microservices and be subject to a separate scaling. Actually, read model managers can be separate reactive microservices. But read models, that these managers produce, are plain resources, which can be stored in a single read-optimized, scaled and sharded resource storage with simplified REST API, where read-model managers just PUT prepared resources, tagging them with some timeout and other metadata.

More than that, aggregates may have REST API as well. Commands and events can be resources that such an API serves. You can POST a command to an aggregate, get back a URL to the command's result, GET event of an aggregate, or GET consolidated event stream for the aggregate class...

Comment: I thought that event store provides consistency guarantee by serving as a single source of truth for particular aggregate instance. E.g. event order guarantee = internal consistency guarantee, as long as each event leaves aggregate in the consistent state.

Comment: As for fine granularity - well, because network and consistency boundaries coincide, doesn't mean that we should always put one aggregate per microservice. Maybe, in some cases it makes sense to bundle few aggregates together, however, from my perspective, it wouldn't make any difference as long as services and repositories they use are remote, or pretend to be remote.

Comment: https://jepsen.io/analyses is heavily needed here to prove consistency, especially in cluster mode.

Comment: Okay, but why would event stream be clustered/replicated between different nodes? Event stream is atomic. As long as each event in the event stream leaves your aggregate in consistent state, and as long as your system is built from properly defined aggregates (e.g. not sharing event streams, not querying other aggregates from write model side, not doing bad stuff Greg Young does not want you to do, and always checking your invariants), why would it be inconsistent in the end? To my understanding, aggregates have exactly zero guarantees their external references even end up at something.

Comment: Yes, for the event stream of a single aggregate that is expected to hold true. But I still to find an explicit evidence. Like when you read about serializable transaction isolation level - you know what to expect. I'd like to have similar claims about event stores. Maybe I was not sufficiently attentive.

Comment: What can we do in this situation: consider banking transaction, moving money from one account to another. Are both accounts aggregates? Sure enough. Then how can you guarantee, that to the given point in time all the transactions, involving particular account, had been processed? Think of sharding and consistency among shards. When I mention difficulties in a distributed environment, I mean this use case. (Maybe correct answer here is that one banking office's ledger should be an aggregate as well, but I don't know, not sure).

Comment: You create a process manager for this transaction. Process manager charges first aggregate. When aggregate emits an event "balance deducted", process manager updates its own state, and emits a command to deposit second aggregate. When second aggregate emits an event "It's okay buddy", process manager has done its job. Given that process manager always knows what its state is, it can rollback from any intermediate scenario.

Comment: Alternatively, process manager can first reserve funds on the first aggregate, and after receiving confirmation it can release the reserve. Or if something went wrong with the second aggregate, it can cancel the reserve, making funds available to the first aggregate again.